# pandas serialization to csv doesn't preserve dataframe and fails plotting

Tags: python, pandas

My code calls an API that returns a JSON which is subsequently converted to a PANDAS data frame before returning to my application code.

Given that the API response should be immutable for the same parameters, I want to cache the dataframe in my filesystem, just so I can re-use previous call responses. For this, I'm serializing to csv, as per suggested by Pandas documentation.

For the fetched data, I then draw a plot using finplot. The problem is that calling to the plotting function fails whenever the data frame was loaded from the filesystem, but is always successful when the dataframe is returned directly from the API. This suggests that the serialization / deserialization using the pandas csv approach is mutating some aspect of my dataframe, but I haven't been able to understand which. Full code snippet below:

```
def plot(df):
    ax = fplt.create_plot("MY SYMBOL", rows=1)
    dfn = df[['Open','Close','High','Low']]
    fplt.candlestick_ochl(dfn)
    fplt.plot(df['MA100'], ax=ax, legend='ma-100', color='#927', width=3)
    fplt.plot(df['MA50'], ax=ax, legend='ma-50', color='#188bc2', width=3)
    fplt.show()

def get_time_series_data(symbol):
    if os.path.exists(symbol_path):
        df = pd.read_csv(symbol_path)
        return df
    else:        
        df = call_api(symbol)
        df.to_csv(symbol_path)        
        return df

df = get_time_series_data(symbol)
plot(df)
```

when the code goes through the file system load path, the plot invocation fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "$USER_PATH\Desktop\stock_backtest\yahoo_finance_main.py", line 89, in <module>
    plot(df)
  File "$USER_PATH\Desktop\stock_backtest\yahoo_finance_main.py", line 38, in plot
    fplt.show()
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 1841, in show
    refresh()
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 1835, in refresh
    _repaint_candles()
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 2425, in _repaint_candles
    _end_visual_update(item)
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 2389, in _end_visual_update
    item.repaint()
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 1089, in repaint
    self.paint(self.painter)
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 1094, in paint
    self.update_dirty_picture(self.viewRect())
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 1103, in update_dirty_picture
    self._generate_picture(visibleRect)
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 1110, in _generate_picture
    self.generate_picture(self.cachedRect)
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 1155, in generate_picture
    df,origlen = self.datasrc.rows(5, left, right, yscale=self.ax.vb.yscale)
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 453, in rows
    return self._rows(df, colcnt, yscale=yscale, lod=lod), origlen
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 460, in _rows
    dfr = df.iloc[:,colidxs]
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1067, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1566, in _getitem_tuple
    tup = self._validate_tuple_indexer(tup)
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 873, in _validate_tuple_indexer
    self._validate_key(k, i)
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1484, in _validate_key
    raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

I tried changing the read csv to specify the read column to 0:

```
df = pd.read_csv(symbol_path, index_col=0)
```

This still fails but now with an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "$USER_PATH\Desktop\stock_backtest\yahoo_finance_main.py", line 89, in <module>
    plot(df)
  File "$USER_PATH\Desktop\stock_backtest\yahoo_finance_main.py", line 35, in plot
    fplt.candlestick_ochl(dfn)
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 1462, in candlestick_ochl
    datasrc = _create_datasrc(ax, datasrc)
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 2144, in _create_datasrc
    datasrc = do_create(iargs)
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 2140, in do_create
    return PandasDataSource(args[0])
  File "$USER_PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\finplot\__init__.py", line 248, in __init__
    if type(df.index) == pd.DatetimeIndex or df.index[-1]>1e7 or '.RangeIndex' not in str(type(df.index)):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

What's the problem and how to fix?

Comment: what does your csv file look like? you should look for differences in the output of your api (`call_api(symbol)`), your csv file and the reulst of `pd.read_csv(symbol_path)`

Comment: CSV header + first row:
Datetime,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Dividends,Stock Splits
2022-12-01 00:00:00+00:00,1.0427528619766235,1.043079137802124,1.0427528619766235,1.0429704189300537,0,0.0,0.0
2022-12-01 00:05:00+00:00,1.0426441431045532,1.0427528619766235,1.0426441431045532,1.0426441431045532,0,0.0,0.0

Comment: you should look for differences in the output of your api (call_api(symbol)), your csv file and the reulst of pd.read_csv(symbol_path)

Yes, I've tried data, I print the data types of columns and they match. I'm new to Pandas so not sure how else I can check for the differences. suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when reading the CSV with pandas, the date index was being defaulted to a string type. This made the plotting library fail because it cannot work on string indexed data frames.

The solution was to indicated Pandas on reading that it should parse the index column as a date. It's not as simple as just seting the 'parse_dates' flag to true, because in such case Pandas parses it as python datetime instead of pandas timestamp, which also fails.

What worked for me is to specify the explicit date parser to be used:

```
pd.read_csv(symbol_path, index_col=0, date_parser=pd.Timestamp)
```